# Menu replaced by ActionBar

Tags: android

Google documentation says menu is replaced by ActionBar in 3.0 and the menu will become ActionBar itself. So I started the emulator of 3.0 and 4.0 but menu still appears as menu. Am I missing something ?

Edit :
I'm using minSdkVersion 4, so will it problem in 3.0 or higher devices ?

Comment: From Doc : On Android 3.0 and higher, items from the options menu are presented by the action bar as a combination of on-screen action items and overflow options. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your application using the API level 15 or higher. To do so, in your manifest, use the following :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

The minSdkVersion defines the lowest API compatible with your application, on which the menu will still appear as a Menu. On Android 3.0 or higher, the menu will appear with the overflow button on the action bar.

Additionaly, you can use the following to show a MenuItem as an action :

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
    theMenuItem.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
```

or in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/the_menu_item"
          android:title="@string/the_item"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

This code will only be executed on Honeycomb or higher.

Comment: the min SDK won't bother the 3.0 or higher device, as they will be compatbile if you use the targeSdkVersion. Though you should use the VERSION.SDK_INT trick to avoid calling methods unavailable in sdk 4

Comment: alright but I'm creating menu by xml, should I have to iterate through all items and call this when activity starts ?

Comment: I edited my answer for this, the xml attribute will be ignored on lower devices

Comment: thats it ? its little confusing, how android will show actionbar ? will it use onCreateOptionsMenu ?

Comment: Yes it still uses the onCreateOptionsMenu, but will display it differently. This is because your app is embedded in the honeycomb version which checks the current device to display as an Action Bar or a menu